# Can not configure prometheus metrics as source in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

My ultimate goal is to get sonarqube metric to grafana.
I discovered a [plugin](https://github.com/dmeiners88/sonarqube-prometheus-exporter) that exports sonar qube metrics as prometheus metrics.

My drill down into the issue shows that I am unable to query the metrics page from grafana so I found the minimum setup I need to test my problem.
I do not need to run sonarquebe to test this issue.

Prometheus runs at `http://localhost:9090`

When I configure the source to be `http://localhost:9090` I can query the stat `go_memstats_alloc_bytes` which is available in a default prometheus server.

When I set the source to be `http://localhost:9090/metrics` and the connection mode to browser I can no longer query the value `go_memstats_alloc_bytes`

At this point I am unsure If I should be able to do so. The SonarQuebe [plugin](https://github.com/dmeiners88/sonarqube-prometheus-exporter) that I ultimately want to use emits a metrics page in the Prometheus format but does not actually function like a prometheus instance.

Is there some way that I can scrape the metrics page to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that  I assumed grafana would read prometheus metrics. Instead prometheus can read prometheus metrics and grafana can use prometheus as a source.
So I scraping is done by prometheus instead of what I assumed grafana.